# What is the use case for Javascript's (ES6) Array.of()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I came across the new [Array.of()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) method that's been finalized in ES6, and I was wondering when one might use:

```
var a = Array.of('foo', 'bar');
```

over:

```
var b = ['foo', 'bar'],
    c = new Array('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: It just adds syntactic sugar I think.

Comment: It is more the brackets that is sugar not so easy to handle as other functions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

instantiating an Array with a number creates an array with that many slots.

```
new Array(2);
> [undefined x 2]
```

instantiating using `Array.of` creates an array with those elements.

```
Array.of(2)
> [2]
```

The point of `Array.of` is to solve the issue where you want to pass a type around that gets constructed later, which in the special case of array is problematic when it receives a single argument. For instance:

```
function build(myItem, arg){
  return new myItem(arg);
}
```

Which would give:

```
console.log(build(Array, 2));
> [undefined x 2]
// ??? Can't pass the literal definition:
//console.log(build([, 1))
console.log(build(Array.of, 2));
> [2]
```

Or to use even more of ES6 as an example:

```
var params = [2,3];
console.log(new Array(...params));
// [2,3]
console.log(new Array.of(...params));
// [2,3]
params = [2];
console.log(new Array(...params));
// [undefined x2]
console.log(new Array.of(...params));
// [2]
```

`Array.of` consistently does what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I googled it for you, and [the first result](http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/es6-array-methods.html) had a great example:

> #### Array.of(...items)
>
> If you want to turn several values into an array, you should always
>   use an array literal, especially since the array constructor doesn’t
>   work properly if there is a single value that is a number ([more information](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch18.html#array_constructor) on this quirk):
>
> ```
> new Array(3, 11, 8)
> // => [ 3, 11, 8 ]
> new Array(3)
> // => [ , ,  ,]
> new Array(3.1)
> // => RangeError: Invalid array length
> ```
>
> But how are you supposed to turn values into an instance of a
>   sub-constructor of Array then? This is where `Array.of()` helps
>   (remember that sub-constructors of Array inherit all of Array’s
>   methods, including `of()`).
>
> ```
> class MyArray extends Array {
>     ...
> }
> console.log(MyArray.of(3, 11, 8) instanceof MyArray); // true
> console.log(MyArray.of(3).length === 1); // true
> ```

It's also worth noting that `Array.of()` also preserves Array's API compatibility with TypedArray. With TypedArray (Int32Array, UInt32Array, etc.), `of()` is very useful. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/of):

> ```
> Uint8Array.of(1);            // Uint8Array [ 1 ]
> Int8Array.of("1", "2", "3"); // Int8Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
> Float32Array.of(1, 2, 3);    // Float32Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
> Int16Array.of(undefined);    // IntArray [ 0 ]
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It basically fixes the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) constructor, which has a special case when you pass it a single number.

From the [original proposal](https://gist.github.com/rwaldron/1074126#arrayof--variable-arity-):

> `Array.of` provides a constructor that, unlike `Array`, does not have
>   the special case for `new Array(42)`, which presets `length` (and
>   hints to implementations to preallocate) but leaves holes in `[0, length)`.
>
> The use-case is when you can't write a literal, because you are passing a function-that-constructs as a funarg, and the eventual
>   caller may pass only one number arg, or several args.

It also does help with subclassing, where it can be used as the "literal form" for instances of your array subclass.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.of([elem1], [elem2], ...)
```

returns `elem1, elem2,` etc. in an array.

equivalent to :

```
Array.of = function() {
    return [].slice.call( arguments );
};
```

example:

```
 Array.of("red", "green", "blue")

    [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ]
```

When you need a constructor function (e.g. to pass it to another function) for arrays, this method is useful. That method lets you avoid a potential pitfall of the `Array` constructor function: If it has several arguments, it behaves like an array literal. If it has a single argument, it creates an empty array of the given length.

```
 new Array(3, 4, 5)
    [ 3, 4, 5 ]
    new Array(3)
    []
```

Here is a [link](http://www.2ality.com/2014/05/es6-array-methods.html) to six new array methods added in ECMAScript for futher refernce.