# Easy instantiation of sub-classed array in ES6 / ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've seen examples of subclassing array similar to:

```
class Scores extends Array {
  constructor(len) {
    super(len);
  }
}

var s = new Scores();  // alloc
s[0] = 1; // assign
```

Is it possible to sub-class while retaining the usual assignment style, i.e.:

```
var s = new Scores([1,2,3]); // alloc + assign
```

Also, how do you refer to given values within the subclass?  For example to create an average of the values?

```
  avg() {
    var sum = this.???.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);
    return sum / this.???.length;
  }
```

Comment: Are you doing this with a transpiler, or purely in browsers that support ES6 classes?

Comment: You might be looking for [`Scores.of(1, 2, 3)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31686565/1048572)

Comment: Doing this in the most recent babel transpiler

Comment: Had not seen that before @Bergi , interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to sub-class while retaining the usual assignment style

Sure, your constructor can do whatever you want it to do. E.g

```
constructor(values) {
  super();
  this.push(...values);
}
```

> Also, how do you refer to given values within the subclass?

Since `this` subclasses array, you can just do

```
avg() {
  var sum = this.reduce((x, y) => x + y);
  return sum / this.length;
}
```

---

Note that subclassing native objects is not very well supported yet.

Comment: To OP: That note is very important. [length not being calculated as you expect](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Scores%20extends%20Array%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(len)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super(len)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20s%20%3D%20new%20Scores()%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20alloc%0D%0As%5B0%5D%20%3D%201%3B%20%2F%2F%20assign%0D%0Aconsole.log(s.length)%3B) may be one example