# Array.of vs "[ ]". When to use Array.of over "[ ]"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was doing a bit of reading when I found [Array.of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of).

As per MDN,

> The Array.of() method creates a new Array instance with a variable number of arguments, regardless of number or type of the arguments.

```js
var a = Array.of(1,2,3,4,5);
console.log(a)
```

But if I already know the values, I can also wrap them in `[]` to get same output. So is there a specific scenario when we can/should use `Array.of`? Also is there any benefit of using it over `[]`?

#### Edit 1:

Objective of this question is **difference between `Array.of` vs `[]` and not `new Array` vs `Array.of`**

Comment: [*The use-case is when you can't write a literal, because you are passing a function-that-constructs as a funarg, and the eventual caller may pass only one number arg, or several args. In that case, Array will not do the right thing in the one-number-arg case.*](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2011-July/015841.html)

Comment: Polyfill `Array.of = function() { return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); };`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I have referred the polyfill. Question is when and why would you use `Array.of`.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna No. `Array.of(40)` will return `[40]`. `new Array(40)` will return array of size 40

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm still trying to figure out that use case. If its about cases where we have to pass functions and its output will define values, we can do something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Lgpy5a5t/). So am I misunderstanding the use case?

Comment: [Refer this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686360/what-is-the-use-case-for-javascripts-es6-array-of) This thread might answer your question.

Comment: @Rajesh please change your question tag line

Comment: One usage I can think of: `fn().map(Array.of)` vs `fn().map((...args) => [...args])`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle, I'm unable to get it. Sorry

Comment: On mobile at the moment, sorry. Imagine a function that returns an array of strings, which you want to convert into an array of sub-arrays containing `[value, index, all]`. You could do `['x', 'y'].map(Array.of)` which should produce `[ ['x', 0, ['x', 'y'] ], ['y', 1, ['x', 'y'] ] ]`. Not sure if useful, but that's the kind of use case it serves.

Comment: More generally, if some library code invokes your callback with variadic args, and you want to return those args as an array. It is much less useful than `Array.from`

Comment: @Bergi, this is not the duplicate as the mentioned question is looking for difference between `new Array()` vs `array.of` instead of `[]` vs `Array.of`

Comment: @Rajesh The duplicate compares all three

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly Nope. Please read question properly. Its not about loop. Its regarding a function called `.of` that creates an array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is one subtle difference between `Array.of()` and `Array()` / `[]` constructor. Normally just like `Array()`, the `this` in `Array.of()` will be the `Array` object and it will use the `Array.constructor` which is `function Array()` to construct it's result.

However `Array.of` can behave differently by changing it's bound context. If the bound context can be used as a constructor (if the bound object is a function) it will use that function to construct. So let's bind the `Array.of()` to a function and see what happens.

```js
function Test(n){console.log(n)}
Test.prototype.last = function(){return this[this.length-1]};

var what = Array.of.call(Test, [5,6,7], {a:0,b:1}, 42, null, "this is last");
console.log(JSON.stringify(what,null,2));
console.log(what.last());
```

So we got an array like thingy with access to all <s>function</s> methods <s>plus the ones</s> at our constructor's prototype.

It's best to remember it's [definition](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.of);

> NOTE 2 The of function is an intentionally generic factory method; it
>   does not require that its this value be the Array constructor.
>   Therefore it can be transferred to or inherited by other constructors
>   that may be called with a single numeric argument.

OK this can be very handy for array sub-classing. I know array sub-classing is possible by involving `Object.setPrototypeOf()` or `__proto__` but they are somewhat [discouraged operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf#Quick_Links) and we can still do a similar job with the help of `Array.of()`. So .. once known to be useless `Array.of()` here becomes a hero; may be one of the most useful Array methods. How come..? let's see...

```js
function SubArr(){}
SubArr.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype); // make SubArr.prototype's prototype Array.prototype
SubArr.prototype.last = function(){return this[this.length-1]}; // add prototype methods to SubArr

var what = Array.of.call(SubArr, 1, 2, 3, 4, "this is last");
console.log(JSON.stringify(what,null,2));
console.log(what.last());
console.log(what.map(e => e));
console.log(what instanceof Array);
console.log(Array.isArray(what));
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(what));
```

I have also tried making `SubArr.prototype.constructor = Array;` but `Array.isArray(what)` still resulted `false` though.

Comment: What do you mean by "*thingy with access to all function methods*"?

Answer (score 3):

Although this method might have been standardized, it does appear to be unsupported in a number of browsers, so using it seems risky and, as you note, pretty much pointless.

The utility of this function seems to be for cases where you need to declare an array but don't want to assemble it out of parts. That is, you want to be able to pass a number of arguments to some function that then returns an Array.

If you follow the links to the justification of that method you get this:

> The use-case is when you can't write a literal, because you are passing a function-that-constructs as a funarg, and the eventual caller may pass only one number arg, or several args. In that case, Array will not do the right thing in the one-number-arg case.

That's basically a way of saying "this function can receive variable length argument lists and will consistently return arrays populated with the correct values", but as in practice that converts an array to...an array, I'm not entirely convinced this thing needs to exist and apparently many browser implementors are of a similar mindset.

The push for `Array.of` largely a response to the fact that `new Array()` behaves inconsistently:

```
new Array(2);
// [ , ] 2-element array that's unpopulated

new Array(1,2);
// [1,2] 2-element array populated with the provided values
```

`Array.of` will *always* operate like the latter version.

Comment: I'm aware about `new Array(2)` case. But I'm asking difference between `Array.of(2)` and `[2]`. Both will return same output. Also regarding case when you have to send function to get value, can we not do something like this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/Lgpy5a5t/)

Comment: The difference is that `Array.of` is not implemented in some browsers so until such a time as it's supported there's really no point in using it unless you feel obliged to and employ a polyfill. This method is a response to situations where using the square bracket notation would be less convenient or impractical, so comparing `Array.of(2)` and `[2]` is actually missing the point.

Comment: I know IE does not support it. Point is not about using it. Point is, Why does this even exist. What can be that 1 use case where you would use `Array.of` instead of `[]`.

Comment: "*in practice that converts an array to...an array*" - an argument list is not an array

Comment: @Bergi Granted, but to use this in a dynamic capacity with `apply` means an array is involved. Using it in a static sense, like literal `Array.of(1,2,3)` has no advantages over `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating off of Redu's answer, you could use `ArraySubclass.of` to create instances of an array subclass. For example, you could create an Array-subclass wrapper around [lodash](https://lodash.com)'s Array methods.

For example:

```
_.Array = class extends Array {
  uniq() {
    return _.Array.from(_.uniq(this));
  }
  last() {
    return _.last(this);
  }
  flatten() {
    return _.Array.from(_.flatten(this));
  }
  // ... more methods
}

_.Array.of([1,2,3], [3,4,5]) // <_.Array> [[1,2,3],[3,4,5]]
  .flatten()                 // <_.Array> [1,2,3,3,4,5]
  .uniq()                    // <_.Array> [1,2,3,4,5]
  .last()                    // <number> 5
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9L2n2h2/)**

---

#### Edit

I ended up extending this example to use ES Proxies.

```
_.Array = class extends Array { }
_.Array.prototype = new Proxy(Array.prototype, {
  get(proto, name) {
    if (name in _) return function (...args) {
        const ret = _[name](this, ...args);
        return Array.isArray(ret) ? _.Array.from(ret) : ret;
    }
    return proto[name];
  }
});
```

Now every lodash function is available, and those returning arrays are wrapped in the `_.Array` class, similar to `_(array)` implicit chaining.

Comment: Apologies for responding late but objective of this post is understand difference between array.of vs []. There is no need to introduce any library