# Can I create an object for which Array.isArray() returns true without using the Array constructor or array literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I can easily make a plain object look like an array by setting its prototype to `Array.prototype`:

```
const obj = {};
Reflect.setPrototypeOf(obj, Array.prototype);
```

(I'm aware that there are also some problems with the magic `length` property and sparse arrays, but that's not the point of this question.)

I want to make `Array.isArray(obj)` return `true` (of course without modifing the `Array.isArray()` method). The [MDN polyfill for `Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Polyfill) is as follows:

> ```
> if (!Array.isArray) {
>   Array.isArray = function(arg) {
>     return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) === '[object Array]';
>   };
> }
> ```

By using the [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) property I can make `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)` return `'[object Array]'`:

```
obj[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'Array';
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]'); // true
```

Now the polyfilled `Array.isArray()` returns `true` for `obj` (please ignore the fact that none of the browsers that doesn't support `Array.isArray()` does support `Symbol.toStringTag`). However, the native `Array.isArray()` function still returns `false` for `obj`. I looked at the ECMAScript 2017 specification and it says that [`Array.isArray()`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.isarray) uses the abstract operation [`IsArray`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isarray), which returns `true` if the argument is an Array exotic object. If the argument is a Proxy, it calls `IsArray` directly on the target object, so it seems that using a Proxy wouldn't help here.

Is there any way to make `Array.isArray(obj)` return `true`? To make it clear, I don't want to modify `Array.isArray()` or any other build-in objects.

This is basically the same question as [Can you fake out Array.isArray() with a user-defined object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8672119/3853934), but it was asked 5 years ago, and the answers are based on the ECMAScript 5 specification. I'm looking for an answer based on the ECMAScript 2017 specification.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm just curious if it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as you already said a real array (which is what `Array.isArray` detects) is an *array exotic object*, which means that its `.length` behaves in a special way.

The only ways to construct that are using the array constructor or a subclass of `Array` (that in turn calls the array constructor) or the same from another realm. Also countless other methods return new arrays (e.g `String::split`, `String::match`, `Array.from`, `Array.of`, the `Array` prototype methods, `Object.keys`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`).
Furthermore, functions that are used for tagged templates or as proxy apply/construct traps will receive brand new arrays, and arrays also are constructed as part of the result of `Promise.all` or `.entries()` iterators.

If you're looking for syntactic ways to create arrays, the array literal will be your primary choice, but also destructuring expressions (in array literals or functions) can create arrays from iterators.

If your actual question was "*Can I turn an arbitrary object into an array exotic object?*", the answer is a firm **No**.

Answer (score 2):

An object either is created as an exotic array or not, and you can't change that.

However, as you mention, you can create a Proxy object whose target is an array.

```js
console.log(Array.isArray(new Proxy([], {}))) // true
```

The Proxy object won't be an array, but will be considered an array by `Array.isArray`. It will be a new, different object, but you can redirect all the internal operations to the desired object, effectively becoming a live clone.

```js
function redirect(trap) {
  return (target, ...args) => Reflect[trap](obj, ...args);
}
var obj = {0:0, 1:1, length:2};
var arrayified = new Proxy([], {
  apply: redirect('apply'),
  construct: redirect('construct'),
  defineProperty: redirect('defineProperty'),
  deleteProperty: redirect('deleteProperty'),
  enumerate: redirect('enumerate'),
  get: redirect('get'),
  getOwnPropertyDescriptor: redirect('getOwnPropertyDescriptor'),
  getPrototypeOf: redirect('getPrototypeOf'),
  has: redirect('has'),
  isExtensible: redirect('isExtensible'),
  ownKeys: redirect('ownKeys'),
  preventExtensions: redirect('preventExtensions'),
  set: redirect('set'),
  setPrototypeOf: redirect('setPrototypeOf')
});
console.log(arrayified); // [0, 1]
```

Comment: I could as well use a regular array, without a Proxy. The whole point is to do this using a plain object.

Comment: With a proxy you can redirect the internal operations to the desired object

Answer (score 2):

Babel can transform a `class MyObject extends Array` into ES5 code that causes `Array.isArray(new MyObject)` to return `true`: 
[Live demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECyCeB5ARgKwKbAC7XQDy3QDsATGAQQCdKx4BvAXwG4AoF4AeyIg5HQDoQHAOYAKKjXj8AlhAm1RRdAHc4SNJiwBKLUA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0)

## ES2015

```
class MyObject extends Array{};

console.log(Array.isArray(new MyObject))
```

## ES5 generated by babel

```
"use strict";

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) {
    if (!self) {
        throw new ReferenceError(
            "this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"
        );
    }
    return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function")
        ? call
        : self;
}

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
        throw new TypeError(
            "Super expression must either be null or a function, not " +
                typeof superClass
        );
    }
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subClass,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
    if (superClass)
        Object.setPrototypeOf
            ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass)
            : (subClass.__proto__ = superClass);
}

var MyObject = (function(_Array) {
    _inherits(MyObject, _Array);

    function MyObject() {
        return _possibleConstructorReturn(
            this,
            (MyObject.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(MyObject))
                .apply(this, arguments)
        );
    }

    return MyObject;
})(Array);

console.log(Array.isArray(new MyObject()));
```

Comment: That's not what my question is about. I wanted to find out, as Bergi phrased it, if I can turn an arbitrary object into an array exotic object.

Comment: I answered the question in the title, for which people might still look for an answer, even if it doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. You can create array like objects quite easily but unlike `.push()` or other array methods which modify the `length` property by themselves, you can never make the `length` property increase by itself when you do like `a[a.length] = "test"` in an exotic array like a `nodeList` or `HTMLCollection`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39956979/4543207) is as far as i could get creating a Frankenstarray without using a proper array to extend but a proper object instead.

Comment: "you can never make the `length` property increase by itself" You can, by using Proxy.