# Why showing empty array error on creating array explicitly by Object.create on reduce function and for of loop doesn't print anything?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, prototype

Creating an array with objects of property descriptors like indexed value object

```
a = Object.create(Array.prototype, {
    0 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 1},
    1 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 2},
    2 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 3},
    3 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 4}
});
//Array {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
//0: 1
//1: 2
//2: 3
//3: 4
//[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

But why it is not behaving like normal array?

```
Array.isArray(a) //false
a instanceof Array //true
typeof a.reduce == 'function' //true
```

```
a.reduce((previous, current)=> previous+current)
//Uncaught TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:3
```

```
for(let i of a){
    console.log(i);
}
//prints nothing
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: See also [Can I create an object for which Array.isArray() returns true without using the Array constructor or array literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41170131/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

You did not give your array a `.length` property.

```
let a = Object.create(Array.prototype, {
    0 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 1},
    1 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 2},
    2 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 3},
    3 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 4},
    length: { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 4}
});
```

The `Array.isArray()` function returns `false` because your object is not an instance of Array; it is an object that shares the Array prototype, but it is not an Array instance. Also, as noted in a comment by an esteemed colleague, your properties should also be enumerable.

Adding `length` will make your `.reduce()` work, but you still won't have an actual Array; many other things won't work.

Comment: Also, the element properties should be `enumerable: true`. But it still won't be an *array*. `length` isn't really a data property, for one thing, even though its descriptor claims it is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wondered that, and you're of course almost certainly correct, but at least in Node once I added the length, the `.reduce()` call worked. I guess that's because inside `.reduce()` it's (essentially) a simple `for` loop, so they don't need to be enumerable.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right; it would help to know why the OP is trying to do this.

Comment: Yup, exactly. `for-of` should work too. But adding new elements via assignment (`a[a.length] = 4`) won't work, nor will assigning to `length` to throw away elements at the end. And yeah, I was about to ask the same question when Bergi did. :-D *Edit:* Er, when **you** did. (My eye is playing up today. 8 weeks post surgery. :-( )

Comment: @Pointy then can you tell where this part of code lives that controls maintaining the `.length` property and other stuff if it is not in the prototype chain and not in direct-child of the objcet?

Comment: It is part of the intrinsic behavior of Array instances. If you would take the time to explain what you are trying to do, you would probably get more assistance.

Comment: @PriyabrataChattaraj - It lives in the JavaScript engine. Arrays are exotic objects with atypical behaviors, details [in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array-objects). If you want to create a psuedo-array, you'd have to use a `Proxy` (and you still couldn't fool `Array.isArray`).

Comment: @Pointy currently trying to understand the mechanism as clear as possible

Comment: Well you have made progress then. You now know that this method will not result in a non-Array object that works like an array.

Comment: @PriyabrataChattaraj - The behavior of arrays is unusual compared to most objects. They behave a bit like proxy objects, in that they trap the "set" operation programmatically so that when you assign to an array index property, they change the value of `length`, and when you change the value of `length`, they remove any array element properties that would be outside that length. All of that behavior is defined by the specification, but it's provided by the implementation in the JavaScript engine, not something you can reach out and touch, or apply to your own pseudo-array.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for you I just have learned a new topic and tried to understand as much as I can❤

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `length` is not defined here.

`reduce()` and `for of` need `length` property to work.

```
a = Object.create(Array.prototype, {
    0 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 1},
    1 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 2},
    2 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 3},
    3 : { writable : true, configurable : true, value : 4}
});
//Array {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}
a.length = 4
//4
for(let i of a)
    console.log(i);
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

But it will still not fool the `Array.isArray()`

```
Array.isArray(a)
//false
```

This is because the hidden machanisim of **"Execotic Object"**
Exotic Object can not be created with `Object.create()` or `new Constructor()`, this needs to be extended with javascript `class` to create `subclass` [ref](https://forum.kirupa.com/t/js-tip-of-the-day-exotic-objects/643152)

Here the internal mechanisim for `Array` is writtine inside JS Engine itself so it untouched.

## Exotic Objects

Are any objects that have different internal implementations are Exotic Object, for example: `Array`, `Proxy`,  `String`, `Arguments`, `Module`

So, in Javascript objects can be categorized into Ordinary Objects and Exotic Objects.

> **Ordinary objects are normal object we encounter that doesn't show any unexpected behavior.** example: any objects initialized with `{}`

#### Let's see some exotic object's behavior

---

```
const arr = []
//undefined
arr[0] = 10
//10
arr.length
//1
arr[NaN] = 18
//18
arr[null] = 20
//20
arr.length
//1
arr[50] = 50
//50
arr.length
//51
console.log(arr)
//[10, empty × 49, 50, NaN: 18, null: 20]
//0: 10 50: 50 NaN: 18 null: 20 length: 51 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
arr.length=0
//0
console.log(arr)
//[NaN: 18, null: 20]
//NaN: 18 null: 20 length: 0 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Do you wonder why it is happening?

Changing `length` affects the array elements and changing elements affects the array

**This is because array have `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` different then of that `Object.defineProperty()`**

[image]
[link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-exotic-objects-defineownproperty-p-desc)
So, `arr[index]` the `index` has to be in the range of `0 to (2^32)-1` and should not be the word `length` then it will be treated as an index, and length will be updated if index >= length. Else it will be added as a normal object property.

[image]
[link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-arraysetlength)
If now `index` is the word `length` `ArraySetLength` function is called and if previous `length` is writable and new `length` is greater than previous it will set the `length` o array as provided and empty cells will be showed as `empty` by the browser or node.

Esle if new `length` is smaller it will delete all the element until it encounter an non-`configurable` element

```
const arr = [10, 20,30,50]
//undefined
Object.defineProperty(arr,1, {value: 15, configurable : false});
//[10, 15, 30, 50]
arr.length=0
//0
console.log(arr)
//[10, 15]
```

[YouTube video explaination link](https://youtu.be/-5Nmn68xxSU)