# Array.of() not working as specified in es6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

According to documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of), `Array.of()` is an alternative to `new Array()` that lets you create an array literal at run-time even if it's only got one element (a case where new Array() breaks down).  I like that, and have replaced most `new()` calls on my custom Array subclass with `.of()`, but since converting I am now finding errors when I try certain things.

The link claims that `.of()` is equivalent to this:

```
Array.of = function() { return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); }
```

To check if that's true, I wrote this test to compare the real `of()` with that polyfill:

```
Array.of_polyfill = function( ...args )           // Fake of().
{ 
    console.log( args );
    return Array.prototype.slice.call( args );
}

class A extends Array      // So we can peek inside what the real of() is doing.
{ 
    constructor( ...args )   // Using of() on an "A" calls this constructor. 
    { 
        console.log( args );
        return Array.prototype.slice.call( args );
    }
}

var a1 = A.of         ( 5,6,7,8 );
var a2 = A.of_polyfill( 5,6,7,8 );
```

Both a1 and a2 ultimately contain the correct value `[5,6,7,8]`, but internally working with the two lines is inconsistent, as shown in the console log:

```
[4]
(4) [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

From the first line there, calling `.of()` did not result in the whole literal being in scope, but just `[4]`, as if internally it's calling the `A` constructor to preallocate four slots, which is not something the polyfill mentions it does.

I care about the internal behavior because one of the main suggested uses of `of()` is custom Array subclasses like my `A` above, to allow me to specify array literals of my new type.  To that end my `A` constructor should be able to do manual stuff with the literal (the arguments that were passed in) but it just can't access it due to the above.  Is there some other way that gives me access?

Is that suggested polyfill for `of()` accurate or am I misunderstanding some aspect of JavaScript and constructors?

Comment: You are extending Array, but not calling `super()` which needs to be done in order to properly initialize the object you are deriving from.  You cannot polyfill proper subclassing of Array because of the magic `.length` property which does not work with sublcassing in ES5.  You need ES6 for a real subclass of Array and if you have ES6, then you don't need an `Array.of()` polyfill.

Comment: @jfriend00: Can't the magic `.length` be emulated with setters and getters?

Comment: @spanky - Not really.  You'd have to override every possible operation that could change the length of the array to keep track of it.  You can make a new object that contains an array and proxy ALL the array operations to that and then use the `.length` from the actual array that you contain, but that is not inheriting from the array like you show.  Suffice it to say that it's not worth trying to subclass Array in ES5.

Comment: @jfriend00: Hmmm... I didn't think that internal operations actually used the `.length` property internally, but maybe I'm wrong. Anyway, I agree that it's probably not worth it for the OP. Pre ES2015 subclassing of built-in types always seemed nightmarish.

Comment: Don't blindly believe everything you see at MDN, a community-edited wiki. While it's usually of high quality, that isn't always the case. Your title question should specifically be "*MDN `Array.of` polyfill not working as specified in ES6*" - and yes, it indeed isn't. It's a *very* simplified polyfill.

Comment: Sublcassing `Array` in ES5 breaks the `.length` property and it no longer works properly.  It's simply not worth trying to do in ES5.  The work-around is typically to create a new class that has an array as instance data and then proxy whatever methods from the array that you want to expose through your object.  Using OO terms, rather than isA Array, it hasA Array as instance data.

Comment: I would advise you to have a look at [Array.of vs “\[ \]”. When to use Array.of over “\[ \]”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39956979/4543207)

Answer (score 2):

Minor point... `Array.of` lets you create an Array, not an "Array literal". The "literal" refers to the syntax that lets you describe and create an array with its initializing data if any, like `var a = [1, 2, 3]`.

Ultimately, the docs make no claim of complete equivalence of the polyfill. MDN is a wiki, so if the polyfill can be improved, then anyone is welcome to contribute changes. Keep in mind though that it will be expected to work in ES5 and lower, so approaching the full subclassing behavior will be much more work.

Answer (score 0):

So we are mixing multiple things in the question. You are using spread operators where you shouldn't, and there seems to be a misunderstanding about what native code is. Array.of is a static function; creating a constructor doesn't mimic its' behaviour. You can however override the static method and use the spread operator. In this case, it would be

```
class B extends Array {
    static of(...args) {
        return args;
    }
}
```

Or using arguments

```
class A extends Array {
    static of() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    }
}
```

Or just

```
class A extends Array {
    static of() {
        return Array.from(arguments);
    }
}
```

Again, your "polyfill" does too much. By using the spread operator, you'll already get an array. This would suffice:

```
Array.of_polyfill = function (...args) {
    return args;
};
```

Below you'll get three times the same array:

```js
Array.of_polyfill = function (...args) {
    return args;
};

class A extends Array {
    static of() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    }
}

class B extends Array {
    static of(...args) {
        return args;
    }
}

var a1 = A.of(5, 6, 7, 8);
var a2 = A.of_polyfill(5, 6, 7, 8);
var b = B.of(5,6,7,8);

console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
console.log(b);
```

Here's the function declaration in ecmascript6:

```
/**
@param {...null} items
@static
@return {Array}
*/
Array.of = function(items) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that your constructor function is called with the arguments that you pass to `A.of`. That's wrong.

Let's take a look at the specification of [`Array.of`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.of):

> 1. Let *len* be the actual number of arguments passed to this function.
> 2. Let *items* be the List of arguments passed to this function.
> 3. Let *C* be the this value.
> 4. If `IsConstructor(C)` is true, then
>
>    a. Let *A* be `? Construct(C, « len »)`.
> 5. Else,
>
>    a.  Let *A* be `? ArrayCreate(len)`.
>
> [...]

In our case, "C" is `A`, the class that you defined, which is a constructor. A new instance of `A` is created, the constructor is called with "len", the number of arguments that we passed to `Array.of`.

Normally, the constructor would be `Array`, so `Array(len)` would be called. Here, `A(4)` is called. Thus, `...args` is `[4]`.

After that, the algorithm will fill the newly constructed array with the correct values.

That means that the *results* of `Array.of` and `Array.prototype.slice.call` are equivalent, but not the way they work internally.

Answer (score 0):

after some tests, it seems that the actual implementation of `Array.of()` is something like this:

```
Array.of = function() {
  //check wether `this` is a constructor, otherwise fall back to the `Array` constructor
  //maybe there's a better way to determine wether `this` is a constructor _before_ calling it.
  var constructor = typeof this === "function" && "prototype" in this? this: Array, 
    result = new constructor(arguments.length);

  for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i)
    //FF and Chrome use defineProperty()
    Object.defineProperty(result, i, {
      value: arguments[i], 
      writable: true, 
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    })
    //Edge simply assigns the values
    //result[i] = arguments[i];
    //didn't test IE, Opera, Safari or any mobile browser

  //and again, setting the length after the items have been defined
  result.length = arguments.length;
  return result;
}
```

> Why just "something" - didn't you read the spec?

No, this was driven/deduced by the actual behaviour in the browser. And only "something like", because I might have missed something.

Especially the part with determining wether `this` is an actual constructor is something I'm not entirely satisfied with. It may produce a false match *(and then throw)* if you take an arrow function and manually add a property named `prototype`; but that kind of hacks should be pretty rare.

> "After some tests" - what did you test?

- how the function behaves in different environments, 
  attached to functions, to consturctor functions, to functions that ain't constructors, to general objects,
- wether there's a difference between attaching it to some Object, or calling it with `Function#call`,
- wether and what arguments are passed to the functions constuctor.
- how it behaves if `constructor` and `constructor.prototype.constructor` are not the same,
- wether it needs Array in the prototype-chain (to fall back to the Array-constructor),
- *Basically how it determines the constructor function to initialize the returned object*
- what happens if I predefine the indices and the `length`-proeprty (it throws an error if the property ain't `configurable:true`, but only in FF and Chrome)

Comment: "*After some tests*" - what did you test? Why just "something" - didn't you read the spec?

Comment: Thanks. Despite the trial-and-error approach, you appear to have implemented a quite fine polyfill :-)