# What is difference between new Array(...set) and [...set]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I use next code for 500k+ array elements and gets `max call stack error`:

```js
function getSortedUniqInts(arr) {
  const unique = new Set(arr);
  return new Array(...unique).sort((a, b) => a - b);
}
```

But this code works without the error:

```js
function getSortedUniqInts(arr) {
  const unique = new Set(arr);
  return [...unique].sort((a, b) => a - b);
}
```

What is the difference between these?

Comment: On each sort your are initialising the new array which which hit the stack and give error at some point

Comment: @Sohan _"On each sort your are initialising the new array..."_ - That's the case in both versions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-is-arr-faster-than-arr-new-array

Comment: Cannot reproduce (with FF): https://jsfiddle.net/b5svkz6r/ - The only error I get with more than 500000 elements: `RangeError: too many constructor arguments`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar

Comment: @Andreas "RangeError: too many constructor arguments" is at least part of the answer. `new Array(...set)` is a function call with `set.length` number of parameters, while `[...set]` is probably handled much more efficiently by most JS engines.

Comment: Chromium chrashes with that call stack error when the array has more than ~60000 entries.

Comment: See [What is the use case for Javascript's (ES6) Array.of()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31686360/1048572) for why it doesn't work with only a single element. Then use `Array.from(unique)`, which is exactly equivalent to `[...unique]`.